# How can I get keyboard navigation in VS Code dialogs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard

I am a keyboardist: using the mouse is slow and annoying.  There are many temporary files that I wish to just close with two or three keystrokes apiece.  Instead I'm presented with this dialog for every file: *and the buttons can not be navigated either by mnemonics or by tabbing*.   I am being forced to click on every one.

I've been living  with this for a couple of years: but is there any option to get standard tabbing ?

t[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you could do this by switching to custom dialog styling. Ex. put this in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"window.dialogStyle": "custom",
```

This will make VS Code render the dialog within itself instead of using the native OS / Desktop Environment / Window system. You may even be able to use arrow keys (I haven't tested this on all dialogs, but it definitely works for some).